# Django: Check for a Model instance exist in a list or return latest added data

Tags: python, django

I have a `list` of querysets from two different models `New` and `Old`:

Now I want to get the oldest data that was added to of each of the two models or get the id of the latest addition to the model.

```
n = min([p.id if isinstance(p, New) else New.objects.latest('id').id for p in all_list])
o = min([p.id if isinstance(p, Old) else Old.objects.latest('id').id for p in all_list])
```

If, say, we don't have an instance of `Old` in the list and there is not saved yet in `Old` model, I will have **Old matching query does not exit** error.

How do take care of that error by assigning `o = 0` without having to use `try... except`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is not built-in way to escape the DoesNotExist exception.

One thing you can try to do is to create a function that treats it, and you just call it. That way, you would get only one line in the main function, like:

### Custom Function

```
def get_latest(cls):
    try:
        return cls.objects.latest('id').id
    except .. :
        return 0
```

### Main Function

```
n = min([p.id if isinstance(p, New) else get_latest(New) for p in all_list])
o = min([p.id if isinstance(p, Old) else get_latest(Old) for p in all_list])
```

Comment: This did it. Even more pythonic.